# How not to rebake the simulation every time?

Tags: baking, soft-body

I have a Soft Body simulation. For example, I move one effector (Collision) that the soft body only collides at frame 410. How can I use already baked 400 frames for bake next the 100 frames? Can I **don't make again all previous frames** because they haven't been changed? Because of this, I spend a lot of time baking for nothing

P. S. Excuse me for my bad English, this is my non-native language